# Bookdown rendering r-notebook

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, rnotebook

Rendering an Rmarkdown with bookdown as output works OK with:  `bookdown::html_document2` but seems to miss cross referencing (e.g. `\@ref(someID`) when output is set to `html_notebook`.

Is there a way to include this into an r-notebook?